# Working on some maze generation algorithms

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I want to improve my C++ skills ( or learn it properly ) so I decided to work on some algorithms for maze generation.

Here is the gist:
https://gist.github.com/imerovic/0cb7396bb67b345235054b5027d2eadf

I have some doubts about memory management and if I'm using pointers properly.

Please review it because I wanna know if I'm on the right track with the best practices.

Cell.h

```
#pragma once

#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

class Cell
{
public:
    Cell(int Row, int Column);
    virtual ~Cell();

    Cell* Link(Cell* Other, bool bIsBidirectional = true);
    Cell* Unlink(Cell* Other, bool bIsBidirectional = true);

    std::vector<Cell*> GetLinks();
    bool IsLinkedTo(Cell* Other);

    std::vector<Cell*> GetNeighbors();
    bool IsNeighbor(Cell* Other);

    virtual std::unique_ptr<class Distances> GetDistances();

    int GetRow() const
    { return Row; };

    int GetColumn() const
    { return Column; };

    Cell* North;
    Cell* South;
    Cell* East;
    Cell* West;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Cell& cell);

private:
    int Row;
    int Column;

    std::unordered_map<Cell*, bool> Links;
};
```

Cell.cpp

```
#include "Cell.h"
#include "Distances.h"

Cell::Cell(int Row, int Column)
        : Row(Row),
          Column(Column),
          North(nullptr),
          East(nullptr),
          West(nullptr),
          South(nullptr)
{
}

Cell::~Cell()
{
}

Cell* Cell::Link(Cell* Other, bool bIsBidirectional)
{
    Links.emplace(Other, true);

    if (bIsBidirectional)
    {
        Other->Link(this, false);
    }

    return this;
}

Cell* Cell::Unlink(Cell* Other, bool bIsBidirectional)
{
    auto Itr = Links.find(Other);
    if (Itr != Links.end())
    {
        Links.erase(Itr);
    }

    if (bIsBidirectional)
    {
        Other->Unlink(this, false);
    }

    return this;
}

std::vector<Cell*> Cell::GetLinks()
{
    std::vector<Cell*> Cells;

    for (auto& Itr : Links)
    {
        Cells.push_back(Itr.first);
    }

    return Cells;
}

bool Cell::IsLinkedTo(Cell* Other)
{
    auto Itr = Links.find(Other);
    return Itr != Links.end();
}

std::vector<Cell*> Cell::GetNeighbors()
{
    std::vector<Cell*> Neighbors;

    if (North != nullptr)
    {
        Neighbors.push_back(North);
    }

    if (South != nullptr)
    {
        Neighbors.push_back(South);
    }

    if (East != nullptr)
    {
        Neighbors.push_back(East);
    }

    if (West != nullptr)
    {
        Neighbors.push_back(West);
    }

    return Neighbors;
}

bool Cell::IsNeighbor(Cell* Other)
{
    if (North != nullptr && North == Other)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (East != nullptr && East == Other)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (South != nullptr && South == Other)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return West != nullptr && West == Other;
}

std::unique_ptr<Distances> Cell::GetDistances()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Distances> Dist(new Distances(this));
    //Distances* Dist = new Distances(this);

    std::vector<Cell*> Frontier;
    Frontier.push_back(this);

    while (Frontier.size() > 0)
    {
        std::vector<Cell*> NewFrontier;

        for (auto& Cell : Frontier)
        {
            auto Links = Cell->GetLinks();

            for (auto& Link : Links)
            {
                if (Dist->Contains(Link))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                Dist->SetDistance(Link, Dist->GetDistance(Cell) + 1);
                NewFrontier.push_back(Link);
            }
        }

        Frontier.clear();
        Frontier = NewFrontier;
    }

    return Dist;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Cell& cell)
{
    os << "Cell [" << cell.Row << ", " << cell.Column << "]";

    return os;
}
```

Grid.h

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <ostream>

class Grid
{
public:
    Grid(int Rows, int Columns);
    virtual ~Grid();

    std::vector<class Cell*> GetCells();
    class Cell* GetCellAt(int Row, int Column);

    virtual class Cell* GetRandomCell();
    virtual int GetSize() const;

    virtual std::string ContentsOf(class Cell* cell) const;

    int GetRows() const
    { return Rows; }

    int GetColumns() const
    { return Columns; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Grid& grid);

    static std::string DistanceToString(int Value, const std::vector<std::string>& BaseChars);

protected:
    virtual std::vector<std::vector<class Cell*>> PrepareGrid();
    virtual void ConfigureCells();

private:
    int Rows;
    int Columns;

    std::vector<std::vector<class Cell*>> Cells;
};
```

Grid.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Grid.h"
#include "Cell.h"

Grid::Grid(int Rows, int Columns)
        : Rows(Rows),
          Columns(Columns)
{
    Cells = PrepareGrid();
    ConfigureCells();
}

Grid::~Grid()
{
    for (auto& RowItr : Cells)
    {
        for (auto& Cell : RowItr)
        {
            delete Cell;
            Cell = nullptr;
        }
    }

    Cells.empty();
}

std::vector<std::vector<class Cell*>> Grid::PrepareGrid()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<Cell*>> vec(Rows, std::vector<Cell*>(Columns));

    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; ++j)
        {
            vec[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
        }
    }

    return vec;
}

void Grid::ConfigureCells()
{
    for (auto& RowItr : Cells)
    {
        for (auto& Cell : RowItr)
        {
            int Row = Cell->GetRow();
            int Col = Cell->GetColumn();

            Cell->North = ((Row - 1) > -1) ? Cells[Row - 1][Col] : nullptr;
            Cell->South = ((Row + 1) < Rows) ? Cells[Row + 1][Col] : nullptr;
            Cell->West = ((Col - 1) > -1) ? Cells[Row][Col - 1] : nullptr;
            Cell->East = ((Col + 1) < Columns) ? Cells[Row][Col + 1] : nullptr;
        }
    }
}

std::vector<class Cell*> Grid::GetCells()
{
    std::vector<Cell*> vec;

    for (auto& RowItr : Cells)
    {
        for (auto& Cell : RowItr)
        {
            vec.push_back(Cell);
        }
    }

    return vec;
}

class Cell* Grid::GetCellAt(int Row, int Column)
{
    if (Row < 0 || Row > Rows || Column < 0 || Column > Columns)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return Cells[Row][Column];
}

class Cell* Grid::GetRandomCell()
{
    int Row = std::rand() % Rows;
    int Col = std::rand() % Columns;

    std::cout << "Getting random cell at: " << Row << ", " << Col << std::endl;

    return GetCellAt(Row, Col);
}

int Grid::GetSize() const
{
    return Rows * Columns;
}

std::string Grid::ContentsOf(class Cell* cell) const
{
    std::string Row = std::to_string(cell->GetRow());
    std::string Col = std::to_string(cell->GetColumn());

    //return Row + "," + Col;
    return " ";
}

std::string Grid::DistanceToString(int Value, const std::vector<std::string>& BaseChars)
{
    std::string res = "";
    int TargetBase = BaseChars.size();

    do
    {
        res = BaseChars[Value % TargetBase] + res;
        Value = Value / TargetBase;

    }
    while (Value > 0);

    return res;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Grid& grid)
{
    std::string str = "+";

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns; ++i) {
        str += "---+";
    }

    str += "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows; ++i) {
        std::string Top = "|";
        std::string Bottom = "+";

        for (int j = 0; j < grid.Columns; ++j) {
            Cell* cell = grid.Cells[i][j];

            std::string Body = " " + grid.ContentsOf(cell) + " ";
            std::string EastBoundary = cell->IsLinkedTo(cell->East) ? " " : "|";
            Top += Body + EastBoundary;

            std::string SouthBoundary = cell->IsLinkedTo(cell->South) ? "   " : "---";
            Bottom += SouthBoundary + "+";

        }

        str += Top + "\n";
        str += Bottom + "\n";
    }

    os << str;

    return os;
}
```